# Regridding a NetCDF file using bilinear interpolation in cdo

Tags: cdo-climate

I want to change the resolution in my netcdf file using bilinear interpolation from `(1°x1°) ---> (0.1°x0.1°)`. I use `remapbil` but it doesn't work. It returns: `Unsupported grid type: generic`.
I upload [file1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ew64OLY1Af7kMA8KHPSohc_r7bbW1eB8/view) and [file2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z7C7eMjFkJd1eXSxZQ-k7iXtgPAhuocv/view)

The command I use: `cdo remapbil,infile1 infile2 ofile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should be `cdo remapbil,infile1 infile2 ofile`

where infile1 is the target grid you want to map to and infile2 is the data you want to regrid.

Comment: I added an explanation, but this doesn't answer the question. It just repeats the command that the OP states doesn't work. The question was about the error of an unsupported grid type.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that cdo does not like the presence of the variables lat_bounds and lon_bounds.  If you delete these first with nco like this:

```
ncks -x -v lat_bounds,lon_bounds deseasonalized_2002-2019new_grace_inter.nc modified.nc
```

(it will give you a warning but it can be ignored).

Then you can use cdo to remap this file successfully. I tried this and it then worked:

```
cdo remapbil,r360x180 modified.nc test.nc
```

so I'm sure it will also work mapping one of your files to the other (don't forget to remove the bounds on **both** files first though).